# iOS app lags on iPhone 6 Plus

Tags: xcode, uitableview, ios8, lag, iphone-6-plus

I am working on updating my app to support the large displays of the iPhone 6 and iPhone 6 Plus. I am using auto layout and finally got everything looking how I'd like. The app runs great on iPhone 6 (just as it had before the update), however when I run the app on the iPhone 6 Plus, the table views lag A LOT.

Has anyone had this same problem and have any tips on how to fix the issue? Thanks!

** I have found the problem to be related to using AutoLayout in the table view cells. I narrowed it down to when I set the text for the UITextView inside the table cell. If I do not set the text, the table acts normal. However, when I do set the text, the tableview is very slow and laggy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

RESOLVED! Simply had to remove the 'height' constraint from the textview.

Answer (score 0):

While the performance of autolayout is much slower than using autoresizing masks, it shouldn't cause a problem, especially when the problem is exclusive to iPhone 6.

My guess is that your tableviewcells are loaded with images or custom drawing code that would make @3x drawing much slower than @2x.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I was wondering this myself. Is there anyway to get around this?